# Корректное завершение активности при открытии второй

Tags: android

Есть главная активность и меню из которой вызываются еще 3 активности. Во всех 4-х активностях есть код:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_about) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_add) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityAdd.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_edit) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityEdit.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под корректным завершением?

Comment: В общем случае вам не нужно специально завершать активность, система сама решит этот вопрос. Но, если очень хочется, просто добавьте `finish();` после каждого вызова `startActivity();`

Comment: Я запускаю приложение и перехожу на активность AboutActivity, оттуда на ActivityAdd потом обратно на AboutActivity потом обратно на ActivityAdd и все это через меню. А когда нажимаю назад на телефоне, то эти активности закрываются как и положено. А мне бы хотелось сделать так чтобы, активность открывалась только один раз из какой бы активности не вызвали ее) Т.е. допустим мы находимся на активности AboutActivity и из нее вызывает ActivityAdd, чтобы при этом активность AboutActivity  уничтожалась

Comment: тогда finish(); используйте

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что нужно в методе onOptionsItemSelected при вызове другого активити вызывать this.finish();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вариант первый

**Хардкорный**

`finish();`

вариант второй 
  в `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:noHistory="true" />
```

вариант третий
в `YourActivity.java`

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

или

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: Спасибо, finish(); помог.